# python api: I want to make a call to an api from python, and receive json response

Tags: python, json, api, weibo

I'm a beginner in python, and I'm trying to write a program that makes a call to Weibo(Chinese Twitter) API and receive a json response. It's just a basic keyword search and fetching search result example.

But the problem is I don't know how to make an api call from python, so I'm keep getting error messages. The API I'm trying to use is http://open.weibo.com/wiki/2/search/topics
It's in Chinese but basically it says the api url, method -> GET, and the list of parameters I need. My guess is that I messed up with the parameters, that method: GET shouldn't be treated as a parameter but in some other ways which I don't know. Can somebody help??

Below is what I tried. I'm just pasting the relevant part, before this part there is a api authorization codes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# sudo pip install sinaweibopy

import sys
import urllib, urllib2
from weibo import APIClient
import webbrowser

APP_KEY = '1234' # there are real values here in the actual code
APP_SECRET = '1234'
CALLBACK_URL = 'http://111.111'

def get_auth():
# some code here, not pasted

def get_data():
access_token = '1234' 
expires_in = '1234'

# This works fine
client = APIClient(app_key=APP_KEY, app_secret=APP_SECRET, redirect_uri=CALLBACK_URL)
client.set_access_token(access_token, expires_in)
r = client.statuses.user_timeline.get()
for st in r.statuses:
    print st.text.encode('utf-8')

# This doesn't work
# statuses = client.search.topics.get(q=u'eland')

# This also doesn't work
# url = 'https://api.weibo.com/2/search/topics.json'
# params = {'method': GET, 'source': APP_KEY, 'access_token': access_token, 'q': 'new balance', 'count' : 50}

# request = urllib2.Request(url, urllib.urlencode(params))
# response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

error message (url call):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "weibopr.py", line 85, in <module>
elif opt == '2': get_data()
File "weibopr.py", line 57, in get_data
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
response = meth(req, response)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Answer (score 0):

Post your exact error response, but you should retry with:

```
params = {'method': 'GET', 'source': APP_KEY, 'access_token': access_token, 'q': 'new balance', 'count' : 50}
```

You need the GET to be 'GET'

Comment: It doesn't work with 'GET' neither and I'm pasting the entire error message.

Comment: Okay, I would now concentrate on printing out the full URL before you send it. A '403' makes me think that you are pointing to a resource that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of got what I wanted by the following code.

```
url = 'https://api.weibo.com/2/statuses/public_timeline.json'
params = {'source': APP_KEY, 'access_token': access_token, 'count': 50}

# request public timeline
response = requests.get(url, params=params)
jres = response.json()
```

Actually, what I wanted was search.topics API, but it turned out that I needed higher level of authorization to call that API.